# How to implement this Pandas code using Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataset that looks like this (value means how much hours the user played the game):
[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iFWl.png)

I need to calculate correlation between users and correlation between games. In Pandas, on the same dataframe (with user column being an index), this is done like this for users:

```py
user_user_corr = user_game_df.T.corr()
user_user_corr.index = user_user_corr['Unnamed: 0'].values
user_user_corr.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
user_user_corr
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hNth.png)

And like this for games:

```py
game_game_corr = user_game_df.corr()
game_game_corr.index = game_game_corr['Unnamed: 0'].values
game_game_corr.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
game_game_corr
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIcy5.png)

How would I do it using Polars?

I tried to play with `df.pearson_corr(...)` and `df.select(pl.pearson_corr(...))`, but had no luck. Clearly I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the dataframes in "raw data" or code? You could perhaps use `df.head().write_csv()` to get a string of the first N rows of an existing dataframe and then use `io` like here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6669#issuecomment-1434635521

Comment: @jqurious best I could do: https://pastebin.com/DCw0zmgX. There are 3600 columns in the original 

Comment: We don't need all 3600 columns, just a minimal example, like 3-5 columns or so. Not being able to run examples makes it a lot harder to help.

Comment: @jqurious got you, how about this one? https://pastebin.com/kaKNGG03

Comment: That helps. You can edit your question and add it to the code example - more like this: https://bpa.st/raw/K5IH2 - except the `.index` line errors out with that data. If you could fix that and add the `game_game` part - that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

On the polars discord you explained that you also normalize the result by subtracting the mean, and also shared the full dataset. Below I include how you normalize it. I then include a MWE of it, with 5 columns and 5 rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

user_game_df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
user_game_df = user_game_df.set_index("user")
user_game_df = user_game_df - user_game_df.mean()
df_pandas = user_game_df.iloc[:5 :5] # I reduce the dataset to 20 rows and 20 columns

df_pandas.corr() # this takes about 3 seconds on my computer for the full frame
```

Minimum Working Example:

```py
import numpy as np

df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user": [151603712, 187131847, 59945701, 53875128, 140954425],
        "The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim": [171.107692, np.nan, -43.892308, np.nan, np.nan],
        "Fallout 4": [33.725, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        "Spore": [-74.9, np.nan, np.nan, -89.3, np.nan],
        "Fallout New Vegas": [-25.348, np.nan, np.nan, -29.948, np.nan],
        "Left 4 Dead 2": [-20.110959, np.nan, np.nan, 41.989041, np.nan],
    }
).set_index("user")
```

Polars doesn't have a method for calculating the correlation of multiple columns simultaneously, when the columns have nans in them. The `df.corr` method uses numpy's `np.corrcoef` under the hood, and doesn't support nans :(

Instead, my solution involves doing the pairwise correlation of two columns across all combinations of columns. Unfortunately, with your 3638 columns, just creating the 3638**2 expressions takes many minutes, since the following expression takes 60 us, and we need to do it 13 million times.

```
%timeit pl.corr(col1, col2).alias("The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim" + "_" + "Fallout 4") # 60 us
```

This is my, unfortunately, very slow solution:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.from_pandas(df_pandas.reset_index())

game_names = df.columns[1:]
n_games = len(game_names)

# Construct a polars expression for each combination of two games (including the same game twice)
pairs_expr = []
for col1 in game_names:
    for col2 in game_names:
        pairs_expr.append(
            pl.corr(col1, col2).alias(col1 + "_" + col2)
        )  # need a label to avoid duplicate-name-error


# Create a column of game names, and horizontally stack the result, which has been reshaped from a list to a NxN matrix
df_result = pl.DataFrame({"Games": game_names}).hstack(
    pl.DataFrame(
        df.drop("user").select(pairs_expr).to_numpy().reshape((n_games, n_games)),
        schema=game_names,
    )
)
df_result
```

With a sanity check:

```py
# Compare results
# Need to round because there is slightly different numeric precision between the two solutions
df_pandas_result = pl.from_pandas(df_pandas.corr()).fill_nan(None).select(pl.all().round(5))
df_polars_result = df_result.drop("Games").fill_nan(None).select(pl.all().round(5))
assert df_pandas_result.frame_equal(df_polars_result) # True
```